# Android TabLayout TabIcons Alignment

Tags: android, android-tablayout

In the previous versions of the design library, when we set icons for tabs of a `TabLayout`, the icons would show up inline with the title.

But in the recent times, with updates to the design library, the icons show up above the title.

So how can we implement something that shows the icons inline with the text ?

I know that we can implement it with custom layouts for tab titles, but it does not imitate the actual implementation; i.e. we cannot change the colour of the  titles, when disabled.
The actual implementation (without custom views) shows the active tab in white while the inactive ones appear different.

So how can we imitate the actual implementation in a clean way with or without CustomViews, simply with getting icons and title inline ?

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: try custom tabs.. make a layout with imageview and textview and inflate that in tab layout as https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/  number 6

Comment: @AD10 i have already seen that but it is based on the old design library as i already mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want an image and some text inline, the simplest way to do it is to use a linear layout with orientation set to horizontal. You can set the padding between them too as you wish or set the weight if that is what you want.You can then add this layout to the desired root view.